# Add-In for Team Foundation Server

Tags: vba, tfs

Is there any add - in for VBA in [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) for performing source control activities like Check in, Check out ?

Basically, I am developing an application in VBA and I am using VSTS as my version control tool. I am not aware as to how can I integrate VBA with [Visual Studio team system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Team_System) to directly check in or check out my code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, is this VBA in office? If the application can use Visual Source Safe then you might be able to use the [MSSCCIProvider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6). If not then the windows shell extensions (explorer integration) in the [TFS 2010 Power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) might be useful, at least you won't need to have Visual Studio open.